# Why does a Heisenberg magnet break the O(3) symmetry instead of SU(2)?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, magnetic-fields, phase-transition, symmetry-breaking

As stated in the title, why does a Heisenberg magnet break the $O(3)$ symmetry while degrees of freedom of the underlying spins are $SU(2)$?

Comment: While someone familiar with the Heisenberg model will almost surely know this, it is generally better to make the question self-contained. What is "the $\mathrm{O}(3)$ symmetry, and what is the supposed breaking mechanism? There's no need to have questions be one-liners, and a bit of context makes a question also accessible to people who might not off-hand remember how exactly the Heisenberg model works.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Heisenberg model:
$$H = \sum_{i \ne j} \mathbf{S}_i\cdot  \mathbf{S}_j$$
has an $O(3)$ symmetry group rather than $SU(2)$ even though it is expressed in terms of spin $\frac{1}{2}$ operators 
$$\mathbf{S}_i = [\frac{\sigma^x_i}{2}, \frac{\sigma^y_i}{2},  \frac{\sigma^z_i}{2}]$$ 
It is because the Pauli-matrices transform according to the adjoint representation of $SU(2)$, and the adjoint representation of $SU(2)$ is not faithful (rather it is a faithful representation of an $SO(3)$ subgroup) because the element
$$g_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
 -1&0\\ 
 0& -1
\end{pmatrix}$$
is represented by $1$ on the Pauli matrices, since they transform according
$$g_1 \circ \sigma^a_i =  g_1^{-1}\sigma^a_i g_1 = \sigma^a_i $$
Thus the largest $SU(2)$ symmetry subgroup of the Heisenberg model is $SO(3)$.
However, the Heisenberg model is also symmetric under the parity operator:
$$P\circ \sigma^a_i = -\sigma^a_i  $$
This operator lies outside $SU(2)$ (it has a determinant of $-1$). It combines with $SO(3)$ to form an $O(3)$ group which is the full symmetry group of the Heisenberg model.

Comment: Then does the spin nematic break the $SU(2)$ or $O(3)$ symmetry?

Comment: @hongchaniyi Spin nematic order breaks O(3) symmetry too. You just need to remember, a spin system does not have SU(2) symmetry in any case. You can talk about SU(2) only for electron systems where the symmetry is fractionalized in some sense.

Comment: @hongchaniyi Indeed, the point symmetry group of a nematic state is $D_{\infty h}$ , a subgroup of $O(3)$.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more standard to call your operator the time-reversal rather than parity operator, since it flips vectors in spin rather than in real space? (I know this can be a subtle issue, since high-energy and condensed-matter physicists sometimes use different definitions for the time-reversal operator.)

Comment: @DavidBarMoshe FYI I have put a bounty on this question since although your answer is good it appears to restrict to the case of spin-1/2 i.e. enforces the fundamental representation of SU(2). I am interested if a similar argument can be applied to the general spin-S case - and if not why not. Would you consider updating your answer to include this?

Comment: @tparker In the above example of the nematic, this discrete symmetry resides after symmetry breaking as the symmetry which identifies between the director's head and tail; it is certainly a space inversion symmetry.

Comment: @ Quantum spaghettification. Nothing really changes for higher representations. The element $g_1$ (the nontrivial element of the center) can be represented by $\pm 1$ times the unit matrix ($-1$ in half integer spin representations).  The parity operator is defined as reversing the signs of the Pauli matrices in any representation. This symmetry persists even in the classical limit; when the spin becomes a unit vector living on a sphere, the model becomes an $O(3)$ nonlinear sigma model.

Comment: @DavidBarMoshe You say that  "*reversing the signs of the Pauli matrices in any representation*" - but we don't have Pauli matrices in higher representations - unless when you say 'Pauli matrices' you mean the set of Lie algebra generators in that representation?

Comment: @ Quantum spaghettification yes you are correct, the set of Lie algebra generators or the set of angular momentum generators.

Comment: @DavidBarMoshe OK one last thing (hopefully), your argument seems to hinge on the fact that the Pauli matrices transform under the adjoint representation which I believe to be $e^{-i\vec \alpha \cdot \vec S_i} \sigma_i e^{i\vec \alpha \cdot \vec S_i}$ where $\vec S_i$ is as you have written it. Firstly how do you know this is the correct transformation of the Pauli's under $SU(2)$ and secondly in the higher rep cases do they still transform under the adjoint - and again why.

Comment: @Quantum spaghettification, yes the group acts on the generators of its Lie algebra (in any representation) by means of the adjoint representation, because the Lie algebra as a vector space forms a basis of the adjoint representation. The infinitesimal version of this action is just the commutation relations.

Comment: I never said anything about spin nematics - I was just referring to your original answer. The parity operator would negate the spatial position index $i$, and possibly the sigma matrices as well, depending on whether you are considering spin-orbit coupling. The operator that you have defined is the time-reversal operator under condensed-matter conventions, because the spin vector is considered to live in a spin space that is completely independent of real space (indexed by the spatial index $i$).

Comment: @DavidBarMoshe Sorry to come back to this. But I was wondering if you could possibly write down explicitly how the parity operator would act on e.g. the eigenstates of $\hat S_z$.

Comment: Never mind about the above question. I found the answer at least for the two qubit case as that defined by the anti-unitary operator $\hat a=-i \sigma_2$ Ref: http://www.phy.ohiou.edu/~elster/lectures/qm1_8.pdf

Comment: @Quantum spaghettification. This is the antiunitary operator suggested by tparker above and indeed it generates the transformation $P$ and it can be even generalized to any representation. However, the same transformation can be implemented by a unitary operator as follows: The group $O(3)= SO(3) \times Z_2$  is disconnected.  In this case, every operator in the group is represented by a $2-$tuple $(z, g)$, where $z$ can take the values $\pm1$ and $g$ is an $SU(2)$ operator in the representation that you choose.

Comment: cont. Since the first coordinate $z$ is scalar, its eigenvector is always $1$, thus the parity transformation does not change the eigenvalues of the spin operators. Please, see Chung , Kostant and Sternberg https://sites.math.washington.edu/~billey/classes/coxeter/chung.kostant.sternberg.pdf 
Section 11 page 27.